# Not able to center a header

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

I have the following piece of code:

```css
#header, #page {
  max-width: 1040px;
  min-width: 960px;
}
#page {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.pageheader {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="pageHeader">The Header is here</h1>
```

I am trying to get the header to be in the middle of the page, but it is not working. It remains to the left of the page. I tried using `margin: 0 auto;` but that didn’t seem to work either.

Comment: Have you tried `text-align: center;`? Have you tried inspecting the elements with the browser tools and seeing what the box model looks like?

Comment: Class names are mostly case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header is in the center (middle is a term normally used to describe the vertical position) of the page. It is just that because the width is `auto` (the default) it also takes up the *whole width* of the page.

If you want to align the *text* inside the header, then you'll need:

```
text-align: center
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
#header, #page {
  max-width: 1040px;
  min-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all capitalize "header" in your CSS file to match your HTML file where it says:

> .pageheader {

so it becomes

> .pageHeader {

Then use

> text-align: center;

in the .pageHeader section like this:

```
.pageHeader {
  text-align: center;
}
```